# How to install adb for android studio

Tags: android, adb

can someone please help me to install adb. I have downloaded zip file from the official website. I don't know how to proceed further. I am a newbie to this android studio

Comment: `adb` comes along with android studio you can find a descent guide at https://developer.android.com/studio/install

Answer (score 0):

From Android Studio 1.0.1

Go to

File -> project Structure into Project Structure
Left -> SDK Location
SDK location select Android SDK location (old version use Press +, add another sdk)